# Diff btw ServiceTracker, ServiceReference & ServiceReferences

Tags: java, service, osgi

I am new to `OSGi` and have been studying it for a while.

I want to know the key differences in usage and the benefits for *`ServiceTracker, ServiceReference & ServiceReferences`*.

I used an example with both `ServiceTracker` & `ServiceReference` and if the service isn't available then both return `NULL`. However if the service is available then both work just fine, but I couldn't observe what is the difference between two.

Somewhere I read *`ServiceTracker` is a programmatic way to acquire a reference to a service. i.e. write `ServiceTracker` code that "tracks" a reference to another service and let's you use it when it becomes available.* but in actual practice I couldn't see it how its done!

Can anyone plz explain it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend that you use neither!

`ServiceReference` simply represents an entry in the OSGi service registry. You probably mean that you are accessing services using API calls like `BundleContext.getServiceReference()`. This is the lowest possible level of working with OSGi services, and as you have probably noticed it is quite complicated and it couples your code to the OSGi APIs.

`ServiceTracker` is very slightly higher level, it wraps around the lower level calls. The key advantage is that it notifies you when a service goes away, which is very important because services are dynamic. However `ServiceTracker` is still very low-level, and it still couples your code to OSGi APIs.

**I strongly recommend avoiding both the lowest level API (based around `ServiceReference`) AND the `ServiceTracker` until you have gained a lot more experience with OSGi.**

As an alternative I recommend learning Declarative Services. This gives you a programming model based on dependency injection and it decouples you from OSGi APIs. It is much much easier **and** safer! You can start by following the tutorial here: http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html

Comment: Hi @Neil, Is it possible to maven with bndtools? Also, Is it possible to postpone the generation of .jar after the build is executed. My project requirement is to generate the jar at end and use maven.

Comment: Nice answer +1. Btw your book is awesome even if it is only a draft. I have learned most of my OSGi knowledge from it!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Neil said but I need to extend upon it to answer your comment:
If you want to build your project with declarative services using Maven you have to use the `maven-bundle-plugin` and the `maven-scr-plugin`. The former uses *bnd* under the hood while the latter processes your DS annotations. Example:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Export-Package>${project.artifactId}.api</Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>scr</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In this example (which is in the `build` section) I direct the `maven-bundle-plugin` to export all the packages in my `${project.artifactId}.api` directory (this is a convention in my OSGi projects) and the `maven-scr-plugin` generates xml cofiguration based on my Apache Felix declarative services annotations.

I suggest you should read about Apache Felix declarative services annotations and how they work because it will help you much in the long run.

I have an example OSGi application you can take a look at: [here](https://github.com/BlackBelt-OSGi-Training-Material/basic-osgi-example)